# I have an image of an irregular hole in the sidewalk and i want to know how to find the diameter of the hole? Below is what i have tried so far

Tags: image-processing

I have an image of an irregular hole in the sidewalk and i want to know how to find the diameter of the hole?

[image]

Below is what i have tried so far

```
Length[image]

Lenght[image[[1]]]
```

Comment: Hmmmmm.... You're going to have to give us a little more to go on. Image? Link?

Comment: I agree with kale, how about the picture you are working with?

Comment: http://www.donnasbigredchair.love/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/hole-in-sidewalk.jpg    sorry about that, here is a link to the image

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 10):

Your image is of dimensions:

```
ImageDimensions[img]
```

> `{500, 375}`

Here's a way to measure the area of the irregular hole:

```
ComponentMeasurements[Closing[
 DeleteSmallComponents[ColorNegate@Image@MorphologicalComponents[img, 0.05]], 1], "Area"]
```

> `{1 -> 16823.}`

Or 9.0% of the total image area.

Since the hole is irregular, we must use `MeanCaliperDiameter`.

```
ComponentMeasurements[Closing[
 DeleteSmallComponents[ColorNegate@Image@MorphologicalComponents[img, 0.05]], 1], "MeanCaliperDiameter"]
```

> `{1 -> 173.481}`

This is the *average* diameter of all caliper measurements. If you want the min or max diameter substitute with `CaliperWidth` or `CaliberLength`, respectively.

For a step-by-step of what this does:

`MorphologicalComponents` isolates components of an image (use `Colorize` to visualize):

```
MorphologicalComponents[img, 0.05]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Next, we negate the color and convert to an image:

```
ColorNegate[Image[%]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Next, we delete the small components of the image. The default threshold works well.

```
DeleteSmallComponents[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The we use `Closing` to close the interior:

```
Closing[%, 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And finally use `ComponentMeasurements` to find the area:

```
ComponentMeasurements[%, "MeanCaliperDiameter"]
```

Comment: Why did u put "@" signs in between commmands?

Comment: @Isaac That is prefix notation in *Mathematica*. `f@x` is essentially equal to `f[x]`.

Comment: Oh nevermind you edited your post

Comment: The original question asks for the diameter, which I believe is given by `ComponentMeasurements[%, "CaliperLength"]`.

Comment: Area is not the same as diameter. That is why my down vote.

Comment: @yarchik Oops. Fixed. It was a little late last night to be doing image processing.

Comment: Nice, voted up!